# Sencha Touch 2.3 / Cordova : Build run directly on device

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I created an app for android with Sencha Touch 2.3 and Cordova. I used the following command to build and run the apk:

```
sencha app build -run native
```

However, this runs the app on the emulator but I would like to directly run it on the usb connected android device. Is it possible?

I already tried commands like these but it didn't work.

```
sencha app build -device native
```

or
    sencha app build -run -device native

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. There is a difference between Sencha and Cordova commands and both are for different purpose. Once you want to make apk for your android device. Just go through the steps [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). But i will advice you to use build of your app to work with in your cordova app.

After making build of your project, Check the following steps:

```
cordova create yourapp com.example.yourapp YourApp

cd yourapp

cordova platform add android

cordova build android
```

After this you should copy your project and paste it into the immediate www folder of your cordova project. And then run

```
cordova run android
```

NB: `sencha app build native`

Deploy the .apk file in your emulator or real device to test the app

Comment: Thanks, the `sencha app build native` and after `cordova run android --device` did the trick!

Comment: Welcome Dar-Jee. You mixed some of your experience and some of my suggestion.

Comment: add just one more point @Dar-Jee cd to cordova dir... just for a few of those who are starting out on sencha+cordova