# Encounter error when building app in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

Encountered the following error when I tried to build the app.

```
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: No such property : splitFramework
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha\tileconmob\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:378: The following
error occurred while executing this line:
C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha\tileconmob\.sencha\app\init-impl.xml:296: com.sencha.exce
ptions.ExNotFound: No such property : splitFramework
```

What is the cause of this error? Anyway, what is the step by step guide to generate an apk?

Comment: Have you previously made production build of Sencha successfully?

Comment: For your 2nd query, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934104/sencha-touch-2-3-cordova-build-run-directly-on-device/22936204#22936204