# How to build Existing Sencha touch application using Cordova / Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i am new to sencha touch and cordova. So please help me to build a mobile app using Sencha touch 2 and Cordova.

My Problem : Sencha Touch Mobile application using multiple Sencha Application within workspace.Now i want to build Sencha app for Android using Cordova / Phonegap. Please help me to build single apk file for my entire project.

Folder Structure :

- Project Folder/

  - workspace/

    - Sencha App1/

      - app/
      - app.js
      - app.json
        ...
    - Sencha App2/

      - app/
      - app.js
      - app.json
        ...
    - Sencha App3/

      - app/
      - app.js
      - app.json
        ...
    - Sencha App4/
         ....

like this.

i am maintaining 7 sencha application within sencha workspace.

My Questions :

1) Can i build single apk for my entire project?

2) If i build separate apk for each app then how can i integrate all?

3) any other option to build / package for single apk ?

i am still in confusing so please let me make clear and give any solutions. Dont mistake me if i miss any spelling. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check below links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934104/sencha-touch-2-3-cordova-build-run-directly-on-device

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cordova_phonegap.html

Answer (score 1):

firstly i would like to tell you can install/create number of application irrespective of apps Folders or workspace.

Below things you should have to create build.

1. To build an APK you need to have cordova install on your machine.
2. you can also create APK from "https://build.phonegap.com/people/sign_in",Just need to have demo account it will allow you to create android and others platform apps just for once. All you need to zip ur code and upload code to mention link after login with ur credential.
3. Eclispe is also other options

my Question to you

## Are you using Sencha Architect or sencha CMD ?

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: thanks for reply. i am using Sencha CMD 5.0.1.231 and Sencha Touch GPL V 2.4.

Comment: Either Am i want to install cordova in each sencha application. or i want to create only one Sencha application and install cordova. please explain me.

Comment: Cordova is not drive or folder specific its globally on to the machine .Please follow the link to install cordova and then create your sencha app and integrate with cordova                             #http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: i created my project using these links: 
for workspace - http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/workspaces.html
for sencha app - http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/touch/cmd_app.html
for cordova - http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cordova_phonegap.html

Comment: hmmm links looks fine ,what's the  problem at your end ? Have you created cordova/phonegap project yet?if yes the you should find www folder paste your sencha app files in that.

Comment: So you like to say create cordova project within coedova project i.e within js/www/ folder i want to copy all sencha application folders in to that www folder. then i will build and run cordova. Finally i will get single apk file for android. is it correct ?

Comment: yup... go ahead let me know if you have any concern

Comment: sorry for took these much time and i found one solution. merge all modules and make one sencha application. now as usual develop with cordova. thanks man.