# Sencha Touch 2 - Help to create .apk file on PC

Tags: javascript, android, sencha-touch-2, apk

I´m starting with sencha touch 2 tech,and now I´m stuck in creating the .apk file.
This is what I have done since the begining to where I´m stuck:

1. Download Sencha Touch SDK
2. Install Java JDK
3. Install NodeJS
4. Install Ruby
5. Install Sencha CMD

After that I created my app:

In the command line --> sencha generate app MY_APP_NAME MY_APP_FOLDER(I use the folder www of my wamp server)

Then with Eclipse for PHP Developers,I opened the folder and start editing the files to create my app.

Now I have finished my app and want to create the .apk file to test it in a real device(in my wamp server runs perfect).

And I´m stuck on how to create the apk file,I have read lots of tutorials but no one is clear.

Please some help on how to create the .apk file step by step or something helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sencha Touch 2.3 / Cordova : Build run directly on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934104/sencha-touch-2-3-cordova-build-run-directly-on-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve my problem. I found that through [this](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) link it autogenerates the files.
Before I discovered that you need to create via sencha cmd the production files through the command in the app folder:
sencha app build production

With this two steps I created the .apk file,donwloaded and tested it.

Thanks to the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create Simple Android Project in Eclipse and put your **www** folder in **assets** folder.

And write below  code in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
    }
```

Now simply run your Application.

Comment: This will create a file called MY_APP.apk in some folder on my computer?

Comment: No. It will create apk in bin folder of your android application. you should check [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270566-Building-Sencha-Touch-2-Phonegap-Application-for-Android-Windows) link.

Comment: Thanks,I will try the link instructions

Comment: In the point 2 of the tutorial gives me an error:
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 35 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\MobileProject\Device\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:284: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
C:\MobileProject\Device\.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:252: The following error occur
red while executing this line:
C:\MobileProject\Device\.sencha\app\sass-impl.xml:258: com.sencha.exceptions.ExP
rocess: Failed creating background process

Answer (score 0):

For creating apk files, you can create and setup Cordova environment as described [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/tutorials/cordova_camera.html).

For some additional help, see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934104/sencha-touch-2-3-cordova-build-run-directly-on-device/22936204#22936204).

Once you want to make apk for your android device. Just go through the steps [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). But i will advice you to use build of your app to work with in your cordova app.

After making build of your project, Check the following steps:

```
cordova create yourapp com.example.yourapp YourApp

cd yourapp

cordova platform add android

cordova build android
```

After this you should copy your project and paste it into the immediate www folder of your cordova project. And then run

```
cordova run android
```

Deploy the .apk file in your emulator or real device to test the app.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I´m following [link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/tutorials/cordova_camera.html) ,and when i try sencha cordova init gives me an error

Comment: The error(When I execute sencha cordova init in my app path)     

[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Alberto\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.5.87\extensions\cmd-cordova-packager\cmd-cor
dova-packager.plugin.xml:131: The following error occurred while executing this
line:
jar:file:/C:/Users/Alberto/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.5.87/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/an
tlib.xml:584: shellscript returned: 1

Comment: I can not see any error. Please paste the whole error statement.